# How to make WiFi work automatically?

Tags: debian, wifi, broadcom

I installed `broadcom-sta-common` and it caused WiFi to not work , i purged it but i still need to run `sudo modprobe brcmsmac` manually after boot to make WiFi work.

How can i make it work automatically like before ?

some outputs :

```
rahman@debian:~$ sudo rfkill list 
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

rahman@debian:~$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u3 (2017-08-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux

rahman@debian:~$ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
44:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

rahman@debian:~$ cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

rahman@debian:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf 
blacklist brcmsmac
```

Update :
While using wl module

```
rahman@debian:~$ sudo iw list | grep "Supported interface modes" -A12
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
    Band 1:
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
```

While using brcmsmac module :

```
rahman@debian:~$ sudo iw list | grep "Supported interface modes" -A12
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x70
            HT20
            Static SM Power Save
            RX Greenfield
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works on startup now after adding `brcmsmac` to `/etc/modules`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `wl` instead of `brcmsmac` as recommended on [the official website](https://wiki.debian.org/wl).

Also you should unload the conflicting driver witch cause the wifi stop until you reboot your OS.

Following the steps described on the debian wiki :

Add `non-free` component to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
```

Install the required package:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Unload conflicting drivers:

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

Load the `wl` module:

```
modprobe wl
```

[wireless.wiki.kernel.org](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211)

```
brcmsmac

Name    PCI Device ID
BCM4313 0x4727
```

> Please note: at least BCM4313 is not fully supported. Some models appears to work (users reported success), but some don't, and there's no indication that this is going to change. For example: http://marc.info/?t=138817851800006&r=1&w=2

Comment: I've found that wl does work on startup and fixes keyboard WiFi back-light but it doesn't work when changing MAC and doesn't support monitor mode , so i'm back to use brcmsmac and still trying to make it work on startup

Comment: @A.RahmanMahmoud Please edit your question , add the output of `iw list | grep  "Supported interface modes" -A12` , clarify what you need to get working

Comment: i Updated it with both modules outputs